# SharePoint Migration Tool error "Errors or timeout for Server Processing the file: Not all the items in the package have been migrated"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, sharepointmigrationtool

I am migrating SharePoint 2013 site lists or libraries through SPMT(SharePoint Migration Tool)to SharePoint Online Modern site.While migrating it does not migrates anything with below error"Errors or timeout for Server Processing the file: Not all the items in the package have been migrated."

It shows 0 bytes of 0 bytes migrated.

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks,
Kailash

Answer (score 0):

Kailash, here are a few things you can check to narrow down this issue:

1. Make sure you use a **Global admin** account to log on the SPMT. Also make sure you use a **site collection administrator** to access the contents on SharePoint 2013.
2. View the migration [reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/using-the-sharepoint-migration-tool-reports) while the task is in progress via **Migration details** or **View reports** and see what the cause is. If the migration task fails, you should be able to find logs named *FilesFailureReport.csv* or *StructureFailureReport.csv* in the Report folder.

[image]

3. Use the latest **[Public preview](https://spmtreleasescus.blob.core.windows.net/betainstall/default.htm) version** of SPMT to avoid possible errors caused by the tool itself.